# Custom Scrollbar overflow?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have made a cool looking scrollbar. I can not seem to get this right. I only want the thing to scroll in the y axis. For some reason, it keeps on the x and y. I want to be able to type in as much as i want, and it space down when there is not enough room on the x axis.... http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/VgB2F/ What am i doing wrong, and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to have `overflow-x:hidden` and `word-wrap:break-word`

http://jsfiddle.net/VgB2F/2/

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks....Also, is there any way i can add some padding in there to make it look a little non-crowded?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VgB2F/6/.   Note that I've lessened the width and height by the appropriate amount due to the css box model. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Answer (score 1):

replace in css

```
.scrollx{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px; 
    background-color: #2A2A2A; 
    overflow-y:scroll; 
}
```

with

```
    .scrollx{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px; 
    background-color: #2A2A2A; 
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/enve/VgB2F/5/

Comment: He wants it to scroll in Y, *not* X.  It is currently scrolling in X.

Comment: "it space down when there is not enough room on the x axis"  yours just overflows and hides the content.  `word-wrap:break-word;` solves this.